# Create sparse Html table

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I want to create HTML table like following

```
#     Class     Method     A      b      c     d
1     User      get        10     20     30    40
                set        40     30     20    10
                find       40     30     20    10
2     Profile   get        10     20     30    40
                set        40     30     20    10
                find       40     30     20    10
```

I have the following structure

```
export class Profiler {
  constructor(
    public classz: string,
    public methodProfilers: {[key: string]: MethodProfiler;}
  ) {}
}

export class MethodProfiler {
  constructor(
    public count: number,
    public totalTime: number,
    public lastTotalTime: number,
    public maxTime: number,
    public avgTime: number,
    public avgMemory: number
  ) {}
}
```

Is it possible to create such Html table using angular 4 `*ngfor` ? I am getting list of Profiler from back end.

```
getProfilerKeys(methodProfilers: Map<string, MethodProfiler>) {
    return Object.keys(methodProfilers);
  }

<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                        <thead class="thead-default">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Classz</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Method</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Count</th>
                                <th class="text-center">TotalTime</th>
                                <th class="text-center">LastTotalTime</th>
                                <th class="text-center">MaxTime</th>
                                <th class="text-center">AvgTime</th>
                                <th class="text-center">AvgMemory</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="text-center" *ngFor="let profiler of page.content;">
                                <td>{{profiler.classz}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr *ngFor="let key of getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers);">
                                            <td>{{key}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr *ngFor="let key of getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers);">
                                            <td *ngFor="let subkey of getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers[key]);">{{profiler.methodProfilers[key][subkey]}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should be aware that `of getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers)` will cause `getProfilerKeys(...)` to get called repeatedly with every change detection turn. Binding to methods is usually a bad idea. Rather assign the result of the method call to a field and bind to that field instead. For the inner `*ngFor` this would need to be an array.

Comment: Yes i know that but i thought to achieve the look and feel first and than optimize the bindings :)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer problem is i am not able to get the look and feel i want . I want something like the table i posted in the beginning of the post and i am getting now what i posted image in the later of the post

Comment: Hard to tell because it's not possible to know from here what your method calls return. You should update your question so that it provides all information to reproduce. It would also better for you to use static data structures and only after the layout works to convert it to method calls or whatever you want in your real application.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated. its not much but just Object.keys  :))) I assume you were asking about this method only. But this is good idea regarding static data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sparse HTML table'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more easy to achieve IMHO if you expand out the `*ngFor` into its [`<ng-template>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor) equivalent.

Then create one `td` for each Profile and set the `rowspan` attribute on the `td` to be the number of "ProfilerKeys" in the array.

I use the function `isNewIndex()` to detect when the outer loop (Profiler objects) changes its `index` to draw another row-spanned `td`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Profiler, MethodProfiler } from './profile';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">#</th>
        <th class="text-center">Class</th>
        <th class="text-center">Method</th>
        <th class="text-center">Count</th>
        <th class="text-center">TotalTime</th>
        <th class="text-center">LastTotalTime</th>
        <th class="text-center">MaxTime</th>
        <th class="text-center">AvgTime</th>
        <th class="text-center">AvgMemory</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-template ngFor let-profiler [ngForOf]="profilers" let-i="index">
        <ng-template ngFor let-method [ngForOf]="getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers)">
          <tr class="text-center">
            <td *ngIf="isNewIndex(i)" [attr.rowspan]="getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers).length">{{i + 1}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="isNewIndex(i, true)" [attr.rowspan]="getProfilerKeys(profiler.methodProfilers).length">{{profiler.classz}}</td>
            <td>{{method}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].count}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].totalTime}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].lastTotalTime}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].maxTime}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].avgTime}}</td>
            <td>{{profiler.methodProfilers[method].avgMemory}}</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>  
      </ng-template>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
`
})

export class AppComponent {

  lastIndex = -1;

  getProfilerKeys(methodProfilers: Map<string, MethodProfiler>) {
    return Object.keys(methodProfilers);
  }

  // on last call to this function per row pass true for the updateIndex param
  isNewIndex(thisIndex: number, updateIndex : boolean) {
    if (thisIndex === this.lastIndex) return false;
    if (updateIndex === true) this.lastIndex = thisIndex;
    return true;
  }

  profilers = [
    new Profiler('User', 
      {
        'get' : new MethodProfiler(10,20,30,40,50,60),
        'set' : new MethodProfiler(1,2,3,4,5,6)
      }
    ),
    new Profiler('Profile', 
      {
        'get' : new MethodProfiler(60,50,40,30,20,10),
        'set' : new MethodProfiler(6,5,4,3,2,1)
      }
    )
  ];
}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/B5YYn9Jxx9nQCzxlr2VS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works. :)